# Loaders issue while compiling the app through webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I am learning React by trying to create a small application. Have created the application using create-react-app first and able to compile the code properly. However, I tried to compile the app by creating webpack.config.js file but facing below issues.

My webpack.config.jsx file-

```
const path = require ('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = function (env){
    return{
        entry:{
            app: './src/index.jsx'
        },
        output:{
            path:path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
            filename:'build.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
             {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "css-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]

                  })
             }

            ],
            loaders: [
              { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
              { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
              { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
            ]
          },
          plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
          ]
    }
}
```

My index.js file-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import Routes from './Routes'

ReactDOM.render(

<Routes />, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

My Routes.jsx file-

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import Landing from './Components/Landing/Landing';
import WeatherForecast from './Components//WeatherForecast/WeatherForecast';
import WeatherData from './Components/WeatherData/WeatherData';

const Routes = props => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter >
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/landing" component={Landing}/>
                <Route path="/weatherForecast" component={WeatherForecast}/>
                <Route path="/weatherData" component={WeatherData}/>
            </Switch >
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
export default Routes
```

The error I am getting when I run webpack is-

```
ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| ReactDOM.render(
|
| <Routes />,
| document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Babel can't interpret JSX out of the box. You could use e.g. the [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react.html) for that.

Comment: I have it installed in my package.json v-6.24.1

Comment: You also have to include it in your Webpack config. `use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['react'] } }`

Comment: I added this now and ran webpack but still facing the same issue.

Comment: You are mixing js and jsx files. Try going with just js files instead, or changing your loader regexp to configure both file types with the same loader. `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: I am trying to have all files in jsx. I included test: /\.(js|jsx)$/ in my webpack and that issue is gone but I still cannot see my page loading. I get an error- bundle.js:5911 Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.